# Does beetroot and chorizo work together in a dish

Tags: flavor, risotto, chorizo

I'm currently going through a phase of cooking a lot of beetroot.  I also love Chorizo. I was thinking of doing a Beetroot and chorizo risotto.  But I'm unsure if the flavour profile would complement each other.

I'm thinking of trying to balance it with balsamic vinegar and/or using red wine instead of white.  In general can you cook these 2 ingredients together and make it taste nice?  Normally I'm quite good with food pairings (though I generally tend to stick fairly tried and tested combos) but don't know if this would work without cooking it.

Answer (score 2):

As you go further west from Russia the borscht often has pork sausage to replace the beef shin etc. If you like it spicy, often chorizo is then substituted for the plain/spiced/smoked pork sausage

It's not everyone's ideal of a meal, but with a good dollop of sour cream it's great!

Comment: I was thinking off adding some goats cheese (probably crumbled on top). Sour cream would prob work too.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the tried and tested too, what you speak of reminds me of the [Goan pu](http://juratesrecipes.blogspot.com/2009/10/goan-sausage-puloa.html)[lao recipe](http://foodfirst.com/recipe_details.aspx?recid=208) that uses chorizo. I've seen that carrots and other veggies go well with this dish, though I've not tried beet-root, I reckon it should work fine, because there are a lot of [beetroot pulao recipes](http://www.spiceindiaonline.com/beetroot_pulao_0/)

Note that the Goan sausage (Chouriço) used here is quite different, is a spicy version of the Portuguese one.